# "Taylor series expansion" for delta function of complicated argument

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am trying to evaluate an integral, which includes a delta function, as a power series in a small parameter $\beta$. The integral is of the form

$$
\int d^2\mathbf{k'} \, f(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'}) \delta \left(g(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'}) \right).
$$

Here, $\mathbf{k}=(k_1,k_2)$ is a vector parameter. It happens that
$$
g(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'}) = k_1 + \beta g_1(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}')+O(\beta^2),
$$
so the zeroth-order term is simply
$$
\delta (k_1) \int d^2\mathbf{k'} \, f(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'}) 
$$
(the result of the integral should itself be thought of a distribution in $\mathbf{k}$).
I am having trouble, however, conceptualizing what the first-order (in $\beta$) correction to this should be. In general, we can try something like the following

$$ \int dx \, \delta(g_0(x) + \beta g_1(x))f(x) = \int \left(\frac{dg_0}{dx}\right)^{-1} du  \, \left[\delta(u) + \beta\ g_1(g_0^{-1}(u)) \delta'(u) \right] f(g_0^{-1}(u))$$

and then integrate the second term by parts. However, this doesn't work in the above case, because here $g_0$ does not depend on the integration variable $\mathbf{k'}$.

If it's helpful, I can provide explicit forms of $f$ and $g$. But I do have other, similar integrals to evaluate, so I am interested in general features of the problem of finding a power series expansion for a delta function of a complicated argument.

Comment: I am not sure if this works, but what about trying using $\delta(f+\beta g)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, e^{i(f+\beta g)x}$. Then, taylor expand one of the exponentials to first oder in $\beta$ and integrate by parts. You should find then that $\delta(f+\beta g) = \delta(f)\left(1-\beta\frac{g}{f}\right)+\mathcal{O}(\beta^2)$. One reason why I'm not sure this method works is that even though $\beta$ is small, $\beta x$ can get arbitrarily large since $x$ can get arbitrarily large, though perhaps in the limit that contribution is not significant.

Comment: If we're being cavalier, we can also formally write, in the sense of distributions perhaps, $\delta(f+\beta g)=\delta(f)+\beta g\delta'(f)+\mathcal{O}(\beta^2)$. I'm not sure if this makes sense though, and how it relates to the other method.

Comment: The first method seems a bit suspicious to me. It should coincide with the second, at least when $f'\ne 0$. However, if we introduce a test function $\phi(x)$ and integrate by parts, then the second becomes $\delta(f) \phi - \beta \delta(f) \frac{d (g \phi)}{df} = \delta(f) \phi - \beta \delta(f) \frac{d (g \phi)}{dx} \left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^{-1}.$ In any case, this does not apply because here $f'=0$ indeed.

Comment: Actually, here's a way to think about the first one that coincides with the second. Instead of integrating by parts after taylor expanding the exponential, you can write the integral this way: $\delta(f)+\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,e^{ifx}i\beta g x=\delta(f)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\beta g\frac{d}{df}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,e^{ifx}=\delta (f)+\beta g \delta'(f)$. I should say that here by $'$ I mean $\frac{d}{df}=\frac{dx}{df}\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: How do you reconcile this expression with the first one you obtained? By inspection, they only agree if $\delta'(f)=−\delta(f)/f$, which I do not believe is true in the sense of distributions, despite the fact that $f \delta' (f) = -\delta(f)$. Also, there's an obvious problem with the first expression: $\delta(f)/f$ is problematically singular, since the numerator is only supported where the denominator is zero.

Comment: Yes, I think the first one might not be valid.